# Explain this IE event binding mechanism using dynamically generated DOM properties

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer, dom-events, legacy-code

There's an extremely nasty-looking event-binding wrapper I've inherited whose rationale eludes me. All I know is the IE implementation of the plugin that uses it breaks if I try to replace it with a simple `attachEvent` or alias through to jQuery The author of this code has had it in place for so long he's forgotten the how what and why of it.

```
function AddEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() {
            obj['e' + type + fn](window.event);
        };
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
    }
    else {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }
};
```

I'm familiar with the very basic method of attaching functions directly to an HTML attribute or DOM property named for the event hook, but this looks far nastier. Here's my interpretation of what's going on:

Create a string, prefixed `e`, consisting of the event hook label and the string-coerced function (!?); Create a property of that name on the element in question, and assign the function to it.

```
obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
```

The same string without the prefix will be another property of the element, which calls a function which in turn executes the original passed function (using the alias we just defined, for some reason), with `window.event` as an argument.

```
obj[type + fn] = function() {
    obj['e' + type + fn](window.event);
};
```

Finally, use the `attachEvent` method to bind the previous function to the event hook.

```
obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
```

Comment: What is your _simple_ `attachEvent`? The `'e'+type+fn` thing is a little odd, but it doesn't do anything extravagant. Also, what version of IE should this work in?

Comment: I would have stuck to the last line of the `attachEvent` code, with `fn` as the second argument. You say this code doesn't do anything extravagant — which is as may be — but I'd like to understand it. Do you know what it's doing, or why? As for versions, the plugin it was used in provides no functionality for IE6, but there's an assumption the code was part of an old snippet toolkit that was used as a generic event binding shim.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably replace it by:

```
function AddEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, function (event) {
            return fn(event || window.event);
        });
    }
    else {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }
};
```

Unless there is some dependency on the pollution of `obj` with two very strange property names.

Comment: Now that looks a million times cleaner. `event || window.event` is pretty self-evident too.  I'll give this a whirl, see if the plugin still works…